# C++ sockets client disconnect

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

For learning purposes I am making my own TCP Socket class.
The class is intended for handling multiple clients. Each client is stored in a `vector`. I am having the issue of properly removing the client from the vector when it disconnects.
How can I properly remove the client on a disconnect from the `vector` and how can I handle incoming data accordingly? (see else branch).
Currently the console gets spammed with the `std::cout` of the else case on a disconnect.

```
bool socks::start() {
    if (listen(this->master_socket, this->backlog) !=0){
        std::cerr << "Failed to start listening." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening for connections on port " << this->listening_port << std::endl;

    int max_sd;
    addrlen = sizeof(address);

    while (true) {

        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO( & readfds);

        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, & readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;

        // Add child sockets to set
        for (int i = 0; i < this->clients.size();
        i++){

            //socket descriptor
            int sd = clients[i];

            // If valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if (sd > 0)
                FD_SET(sd, & readfds);

            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if (sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }

        // Wait indefinitely for an activity on one of the sockets
        int activity = select(max_sd + 1, & readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if ((activity < 0) && (errno != EINTR)) {
            std::cerr << "select() failed" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        // Handle incoming connections
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, & readfds)){
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *) & address,(socklen_t *) & addrlen)) <0){
                std::cerr << "Failed to accept incoming connection." << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            // Information about the new connection
            std::cout << "New connection : "
                << "[SOCKET_FD : " << new_socket
                << " , IP : " << inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr)
                << " , PORT : " << ntohs(address.sin_port)
                << "]" << std::endl;
            // Add connection to vector
            this->clients.push_back(new_socket);
        }
        // Hande client disconnections / incoming data?
        else{
            std::cout << "Disconnect??? Or what happens here?" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : I added this to the else case:

```
else {
    for (int j = 0; j < this->clients.size(); ++j) {
        if (this->clients.at(j) == -1) {
            continue; // eventually vector.erase() ?
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(this->clients.at(j), &this->readfds)) {
            char buf[256];
            ssize_t rc = recv(this->clients.at(j), buf, 256, 0);
            if (rc == 0) {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected! [SOCKET_FD: "
                    << this->clients.at(j) << "]"
                    << std::endl;
                close(this->clients.at(j));
                this->clients.erase(this->clients.begin() + j);
            } else {
                std::cout << "Client " << this->clients.at(j)
                    << " sent: " << buf << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You [*erase*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) it? I also suggest you read about [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do know how to remove elements from a vector thats not my question. How can I properly distinguish that a client disconnected and what checks do I need to do before I can remove it? And when do I know data is incoming? Also why is the else case spammed on a disconnect?

Comment: Ah okay. A socket that is disconnected in a "nice" way will become readable, with `read` (or `recv`) returning zero. It's well-documented.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so in the else case you'd iterate all sockets in the set, check which one is readable (how?) and then remove it? Or how would yu distinguish between incoming data and disconnects?

Comment: You already know how to check if a socket is readable. You do it with the passive listening socket. And as I said, if `read` or `recv` returns zero then that's the same as "end of connection" (corresponding to "end of file" for files). There must be millions of examples and tutorials about this all over the Internet. A quick search would have told you this much earlier.

Comment: @Kyu96: "*you'd iterate all sockets in the set, check which one is readable (how?)*" - your `select()` call is asking for readability, so it will modify the entries of `readfds` to remove all non-readable sockets. So you simply iterate your `clients` list calling `FD_ISSET()` on each one, just like you do with your `master_socket`. "*and then remove it?*" - once you have determined if a given client is readable, you can then `recv()` data from that client, and if the `recv` fails or returns 0, `close()` that client and remove it from the `clients` list, otherwise act on the data as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your advice. Please see my edit. I managed to remove a client on disconnect as well as handling incoming data. I wonder if there is something left I am missing out, important checks that need to be done or other things I haven't yet taken into consideration. I want to be sure I am not missing anything important ;)

Comment: @Kyu96: 1) your `clients` list should NEVER have items with a value of -1 in it. If it does, you have other bugs in your code. 2) don't use `at()` in your loop, it is wasted overhead. Use `operator[]` instead. 3) if you want to modify `clients` while you are looping through it, DON'T increment `j` on every loop iteration, or you will skip a client whenever you erase a client. Otherwise, use iterators instead of indexes, as `erase()` returns an iterator to the next element in the list. 4) you are not handling the case of `recv()` returning -1 on error. You need to `close()` those clients, too.

Comment: @Kyu96: I added an answer with my comments for you

Comment: I strongly suggest switching from `select()` to `poll()`.  It is the perfect companion to a vector of sockets.

Comment: @BenVoigt is `poll()` more efficient than `select()` aside the limitation of `select()` to ~1024 clients?

Comment: @Kyu96: Yes, you don't have to rebuild the fdset every time, because the events-of-interest you pass into `poll()` and events-that-happened that `poll()` sets before returning are stored in different variables.  The annoyance is probably more important than the efficiency difference, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select()` call is asking for readable sockets only, so upon exit it will have modified your `readfds` to remove all non-readable sockets.  So, you simply need to iterate through your `clients` list calling `FD_ISSET()` on each socket, just like you do with your `master_socket`.  And you shouldn't be doing that iteration in an `else` block anyway, as the listening socket could be receiving new inbound clients at the same time that established clients are also receiving data.

Once you have determined if a given client is readable, you can then `recv()` data from that client, and if the `recv` calls returns -1 (error) or 0 (peer disconnected gracefully), `close()` that client and remove it from the `clients` list.  Otherwise, act on the data as needed.

Other things to consider:

1. your `clients` list should NEVER have items with a value of -1 in it.  If it does, you have bigger problems with your code that you need to fix.
2. don't use `clients.at()` in your loop, it is just wasted overhead.  Use the list's `operator[]` instead.
3. if you want to modify the `clients` list while looping through it, DON'T increment `j` on every loop iteration, or you will skip a client whenever you erase a client.  Otherwise, use iterators instead of indexes, as `erase()` returns an iterator to the next element in the list.  Consider using iterators anyway, since you are erasing an iterator, not an index.
4. you are not handling the case where `recv()` may return -1 on error. You need to `close()` and remove failed clients, not just disconnected clients.
5. you are assuming `recv()` returns null-terminated data, which is not guaranteed even if the sender actually sends null-terminated data.  TCP is a streaming transport, any given read may return fewer bytes than requested. You must pay attention to the return value of `recv()` to know how many bytes were actually received, otherwise you risk going out of bounds of your buffer.

Try something more like this:

```
bool socks::start() {
    if (listen(master_socket, backlog) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to start listening." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening for connections on port " << listening_port << std::endl;

    fd_set readfds;
    char buf[256];

    while (true) {

        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        int max_sd = master_socket;

        // Add child sockets to set
        for (size_t i = 0; i < clients.size(); ++i) {
            //socket descriptor
            int sd = clients[i];    
            FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if (sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }

        // Wait indefinitely for an activity on one of the sockets
        int activity = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (activity < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            std::cerr << "select() failed" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        // Handle incoming connections
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) {
            sockaddr_in address;
            socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);
            int new_socket = accept(master_socket, (sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen);
            if (new_socket < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to accept incoming connection." << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            // Information about the new connection
            std::cout << "New connection : "
                      << "[SOCKET_FD : " << new_socket
                      << " , IP : " << inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr)
                      << " , PORT : " << ntohs(address.sin_port)
                      << "]" << std::endl;

            // Add connection to vector
            clients.push_back(new_socket);    
        }

        // Handle client disconnections / incoming data?
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < clients.size()) {
            int sd = clients[j];
            if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)) {
                ssize_t rc = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
                if (rc <= 0) {
                    std::cout << "Client " << (rc < 0) ? "read error" : "disconnected" << "! [SOCKET_FD: " << sd << "]" << std::endl;
                    close(sd);
                    clients.erase(clients.begin() + j);
                    continue;
                }
                std::cout << "Client " << sd << " sent: ";
                std::cout.write(buf, rc);
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            ++j;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Do note that `select()` has a maximum number of sockets it can handle at a time.  If you end up with more clients than `select()` can handle, you will have to break up the list into multiple calls to `select()` (possible calling them in worker threads for parallel processing), or switch to `(e)poll()` instead:

```
bool socks::start() {
    if (listen(master_socket, backlog) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to start listening." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening for connections on port " << listening_port << std::endl;

    std::vector<pollfd> readfds;
    char buf[256];
    pollfd pfd;

    //add master socket to set
    pfd.fd = master_socket;
    pfd.events = POLLIN;
    pfd.revents = 0;
    readfds.push_back(pfd);

    while (true) {

        // Wait indefinitely for an activity on one of the sockets
        int activity = poll(&readfds[0], readfds.size(), -1);
        if (activity < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            std::cerr << "poll() failed" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        // Handle incoming connections, client disconnections, and incoming data
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < readfds.size()) {
            if (readfds[j].revents == 0) {
                ++j;
                continue;
            }

            int sd = readfds[j].fd;

            if (readfds[j].revents & POLLIN) {
                if (sd == master_socket) {
                    sockaddr_in address;
                    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);
                    int new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen);
                    if (new_socket < 0) {
                        std::cerr << "Failed to accept incoming connection." << std::endl;
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Information about the new connection
                    std::cout << "New connection : "
                              << "[SOCKET_FD : " << new_socket
                              << " , IP : " << inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr)
                              << " , PORT : " << ntohs(address.sin_port)
                              << "]" << std::endl;

                    // Add connection to vectors

                    clients.push_back(new_socket);    

                    pfd.fd = new_socket;
                    pfd.events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP;
                    pfd.revents = 0;
                    readfds.push_back(pfd);
                }
                else {
                    ssize_t rc = recv(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
                    if (rc > 0) {
                        std::cout << "Client " << sd << " sent: ";
                        std::cout.write(buf, rc);
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
                    else if (rc == 0) {
                        readfds[j].revents |= POLLHUP;
                    } else {
                        readfds[j].revents |= POLLERR;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (readfds[j].revents != POLLIN) {
                if (sd == master_socket) {
                    ...
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Client " << (readfds[j].revents & POLLERR) ? "read error" : "disconnected" << "! [SOCKET_FD: " << sd << "]" << std::endl;
                    close(sd);
                    clients.erase(std::find(clients.begin(), clients.end(), sd));
                    readfds.erase(readfds.begin() + j);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            ++j;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful advice! It definitly helped me to understand what I can improve at my code and what else to look into. Regarding the maximum `select()` can hande - isn't it 1024 if I am not mistaken? What will happen if more clients connect? Will this lead to a crash?

Comment: @Kyu96 "*Executing FD_CLR() or FD_SET() with a value of fd that is negative or is equal to or larger than FD_SETSIZE will result in undefined behavior.*"

Comment: Is it complicated to change your example into a poll-based example? It seems that `poll` would be a better choice over `select` because from what I understad its faster and not limited to a certain amount of clients?

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help! Case I want to send data from the sever to the clients do I need to add another `std::vector<pollfd>` for writing?

Comment: @Kyu96 no. Simply include `POLLOUT` in the events that you poll for in the existing vector. That is the equivalent of `writefds` in `select()`.

Comment: I actually have one more question related to your code examples. When waiting for incoming connections the main thread is getting blocked. Wouldn't it be wise to create a new thread for listening and eventually also when waiting for incoming data? How would you manage all these threads, without having to fear zombie-threads (non closed threads after completion) after starting/stopping listening multiple times? What is the best way to handle incoming and outgoing data properly threaded?

Comment: When using polling the waiting still blocks the main thread and therefore freezes the UI. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kyu96 you shouldn't be doing socket I/O on a UI thread to begin with. Either put a timeout on the polling so you can process UI messages, or move the polling to another thread. You don't need separate threads for accepting connections and reading/writing data, though